# Safari desktop video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video, browser, safari

I trying to inserting and playing a live stream inside video tag. In chrome it works perfectly, video start playing as soon as possible, but in safari I can see when live stream is available and poster was removed, but until I switch between browser tabs, video is not start playing. Also video will play if I switch between applications windows e.g. I switch to slack then back to the safari and video will playing

Comment: Sample code or video examples would be useful to help you debug.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/E2x0zZ.jpg
code snippet I'm using ^^. But same code in chrome works as expected, so my post question is more about safari works

Comment: so for some reason Safari is not updating the video tag until the page is placed back in the foreground.  Perhaps just forcing the video tag to start playback with ```videoTag.play()``` will jumpstart Safari (and not hurt in chrome)

Comment: I”ll try manually calling play and pause, but this not work